# What is the default method for the p.adjust method in R?

Tags: r

Hopefully this isn't a silly question, but I'm having trouble finding out what the default adjustment method is for `p.adjust` in R. There's nothing in `?p.adjust` about a default method.

I *think* it is the Holm method but I can't find documentation that shows that.

Comment: if you look at the first line of `p.adjust` it has,
`match.arg(method)`, where the default is `method=p.adjust.methods`.
A quick look at the details of `match.arg` says that *".. and 
returns the first element"*

Comment: Thank you, I would not have thought to look at that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at `?p.adjust`, you will see:

```
 p.adjust.methods
 # c("holm", "hochberg", "hommel", "bonferroni", "BH", "BY",
 #   "fdr", "none")
```

So the default, without particular specification, is the first one: "holm".

---

I think this question is really related to how R gets default function argument value. I will show some functions that I am familiar:

```
 density(x, bw = "nrd0", adjust = 1,
         kernel = c("gaussian", "epanechnikov", "rectangular",
                    "triangular", "biweight",
                    "cosine", "optcosine"),
         weights = NULL, window = kernel, width,
         give.Rkern = FALSE,
         n = 512, from, to, cut = 3, na.rm = FALSE, ...)

 ksmooth(x, y, kernel = c("box", "normal"), bandwidth = 0.5,
         range.x = range(x),
         n.points = max(100L, length(x)), x.points)

 loess(formula, data, weights, subset, na.action, model = FALSE,
       span = 0.75, enp.target, degree = 2,
       parametric = FALSE, drop.square = FALSE, normalize = TRUE,
       family = c("gaussian", "symmetric"),
       method = c("loess", "model.frame"),
       control = loess.control(...), ...)
```

We see that some function argument has only one default value, like `bw = "nrd0"` in `density()`; while some have a group of values, like

```
kernel = c("gaussian", "epanechnikov", "rectangular",
                    "triangular", "biweight",
                    "cosine", "optcosine")
```

in `density()`. Well, without exception, unless specific user input is found, the first element of those defaults is used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be "holm":

```
set.seed(1)
ps  <- runif(20, max=.2)
def <- p.adjust(ps)
bon <- p.adjust(ps, method="bonferroni")
hol <- p.adjust(ps, method="holm")
hoc <- p.adjust(ps, method="hochberg")
hom <- p.adjust(ps, method="hommel")
bh  <- p.adjust(ps, method="BH")
by  <- p.adjust(ps, method="BY")
non <- p.adjust(ps, method="none")
lst <- list(bon, hol, hoc, hom, bh, by, non)

for(i in 1:6){
  print(def==lst[[i]])
}
#  [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [10]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [19]  TRUE  TRUE
#  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [11] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [19] FALSE FALSE
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [19] FALSE FALSE
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [19] FALSE FALSE
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [10] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [19] FALSE FALSE
```

Note that "holm" is the first option listed for `method` in the documentation.  That usually means it is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it even using a toy example. 'holm' is the only one that gives you the same result compared to when you don't specify a method.

```
a <- c(0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.1)

p.adjust(a, n = 100)
[1] 0.99 0.99 0.10 1.00
p.adjust(a, method = "holm", n = 100)
[1] 0.99 0.99 0.10 1.00# Same as above when no method specified

p.adjust(a, method = "hochberg", n = 100)
[1] 0.98 0.98 0.10 1.00
p.adjust(a, method = "hommel", n = 100)
[1] 0.98 0.98 0.10 1.00
p.adjust(a, method = "bonferroni", n = 100)
[1] 1.0 1.0 0.1 1.0
p.adjust(a, method = "BH", n = 100)
[1] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.1000000 1.0000000
p.adjust(a, method = "BY", n = 100)
[1] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.5187378 1.0000000
p.adjust(a, method = "fdr", n = 100)
[1] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.1000000 1.0000000
```